# SharedPreferences get deleted randomly

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

A user of my android app has the following problem:

Every few days the SharedPreferences of my app get deleted and the app goes back to the default values of the settings.
In the app are settings like the IP-address of a server and things like that...

The strange thing is, this never happened on any other device. He uses Android 4.4 (I have a test device with 4.4 too - No problems at all)

I guess this problem is pretty hard to solve, since there are so many possibilities. But maybe one of you faced a similar issue.

Comment: SharedPreferences get deleted when the Mobile lacks in performance when too many apps are running. Android automatically closes apps, clears caches, etc. (and also deletes SharedPreferences) if needed to free the memory usage. So it's basically a problem on his end. He either runs too many apps or he uses some heavy app. Apps with a lot of NoSQL queries from and to the local database are a pretty likely cause for Android to clear chaches. Although it can have all kind of possibilities. Perhaps his Android mobile is just broken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438195/sharedpreferences-are-sometimes-deleted

Answer (score 6):

If he uses some utility app that cleans app cache (or user data) to create some free space, it might be deleting the shared preferences. If an app's data is cleared, all shared preferences get deleted.

Comment: Thank you, I will wait if the problem happens again and if yes, I will ask him if he used something like that.

Comment: how to avoid it?